# NetSuite % Breakdown of Sales orders that went to a specific Location

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to make a saved search to calculate the percentage of sales orders that went to each of my 5 locations. Essentially I need to make a calculated column that divides the count of my sales orders at each location by the count of all the sales orders over that date range. I stuck on this formula, does anyone have any tips?

I have tried to group by location and used the count of the internal IDs, but keep getting error messages.